# Pass variable within controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to pass a variable from one controller function to an other. In other words, how can I access the variable from an other function, within the same controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Pascal mentioned, one way is to set a property on the object:

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController
{

  public $foo = '';  

  public function index()
  {
    $this->foo = 'bar';
  }

  public function view($id = null)
  {
    $baz = $this->foo;

    $this->set('baz', $baz);
  }

}
```

Or pass it as argument:

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController
{

  public function index()
  {
    $foo = "bar";
    $this->view($foo)
  }

  public function view($param)
  {
    $this->set('bar', $param);
  }

}
```

Comment: As noted below, "defining a property in the controller is not persistent after subsequent calls to the controller."

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that defining a property in the controller is not persistent after subsequent calls to the controller.

However, defining a property in the model is persistent between controller function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Consdidering your Controllers are classes, you have two solutions :

- pass the variable as a parameter from one method to the other ; see [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)
- or store the data in a class-property, visible from all methods in the same class ; see [Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Which one of those solutions should you use ?

I suppose it depends on the situation :

- If you only have a few data to share between only two methods, passing them as parameters is probably the way to go.
- If you have data that should be shared by all methods, the second one is the right solution.
- If you are between those two cases... You'll probably have to judge by yourself which one is the most practical solution...